# jinja2.exceptions.TemplateNotFound error with airflow bash operator

Tags: python, jinja2, airflow

Running the below DAG task.

```
dag = DAG(
    'TEST',
    default_args=default_args,
    schedule_interval=None,
    max_active_runs=1)

create_command0 = "./auto_script/jobs/start_mail.sh"
t0 = BashOperator(
    task_id='start_mail',
    bash_command=create_command0,
    dag=dag,
    env={
        'subject_area': feed_name,
        'customer_name': customer,
        'job_home': home,
        'job_start_time': start_time})
```

DAG is keep on failing with the error, "**jinja2.exceptions.TemplateNotFound: ./auto_script/jobs/start_mail.sh"**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a common error with airflow. Try the following. This should be done in general so will hopefully help with your specific issue.

- You need to add a space at the end of the command like so. (**Notice the space at end of string**)
- You should also use the full path if possible instead of the relative path where '/home/user/bob/airflow/' is the location.

```
create_command0 = "/home/user/bob/airflow/auto_script/jobs/start_mail.sh "
```

instead of

```
create_command0 = "/home/user/bob/airflow/auto_script/jobs/start_mail.sh"
```

Hope that helps.
More information on the exact cause can be found in the link below.
https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/AIRFLOW/Common+Pitfalls

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Have tried the same but it didn't help to resolve the issue.

Comment: When I add a space, I am getting "[2019-09-20 08:09:38,913] {{bash_operator.py:128}} INFO - /tmp/airflowtmpzbgpqsqq/start_mailzxam4vvn: line 1: ./auto_script/jobs/start_mail.sh: No such file or directory"

Comment: No worries, Where are you running airflow from ? It's better to specify the full path of script being run if possible.